# How do I set user permission types in Yii2 Advance App

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

So I have different User Roles which are National Admin, Regional Admin, Municipal Admin and External User. On my user table, I have the column field "role" I want the External User to not be able to Create something on the CRUD that I generated. How do I do that?

```
public function behaviors(){
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['index','create','update','view'],
            'rules' => [
                // allow authenticated users
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                // everything else is denied
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at this:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#rbac?

1. Use `yii\rbac\DbManager` class as Authentication Manager Component
2. Run migration to create security tables
3. Define your low level permissions.
4. Add them under `roles` in `behaviors\access`
5. Group them into higher level permissions and roles; assign to the
   users
6. Use rules for your custom logic.
7. Assign default permissions.

---

*Side Note:* I recommend having a separate permission for each individual CRUD function (and other actions). That way you will never find yourself in a situation where a single permission grants too much access.

**Example:** Lower level permissions:

- `createUser`
- `updateUser`
- `viewUser`
- `deleteUser`
- `activateUser`
- `deactivateUser`

Combine all of the permissions above  into an `allActionUser` group, and assign it to `AdminRole` role.

Combine `viewUser`, `activateUser`, `deactivateUser` into a `powerUser` group and assign it to `powerUserRole` role.

Then assign roles, groups and/or individual granular permissions to the users. This will give you maximum versatility in assigning permissions and complying with your business needs (or your use case).

Spend extra time to understand rules and use them extensively to define your custom logic. Covering something with controller code works for one function, but you will quickly find out that it does not scale well.

A good example of a rule is `updateUserSelf`. You probably don't want to assign `updateUser` permission to the end users, as it will be a *wild-west* as everyone will be updating everyone's information. But you certainly want to give your end users an ability to update their own info. That is where the rules come handy.

Comment: You are very welcome. Also, welcome to the StackOverflow community. Looks like this is your first question. For best results try to be as descriptive as possible in your questions. Checkout this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it as correct.